# How to "Deploy as Sheets add-on..." to distribute sheet with pre-installed add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-script-addon

I want to publish a Google Sheets add-on and distribute it to a trusted list of testers. I do not need to publish to the G-Suite Marketplace for general public use. But I do need to have a link I can share privately with my group. Alternatively, and preferably, I would like to share a spreadsheet (the container to which the add-on script is bound) with the list of users and have that spreadsheet already have the add-on pre-installed.

In order to accomplish this, I have followed [the example in this video](https://youtu.be/6jcc3xm7aRU?t=702). I was able to follow the video exactly until I got to 11:42 (where the link is queued). At that point, the video maker clicks the following button <kbd>Deploy as Sheets add-on...</kbd> from the dropdown menu as follows...

#### When I do this

[image]

#### The screen I want to see

...he gets the following screen.

[image]

#### The screen I actually see instead

But when I click the same button, I get the following screen instead.

[image]

It's worth noting that I have not paid the $5 fee — because I haven't seen the prompt screen. Where is it? How can I find the screen where I can pay the $5 fee?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot, you have to also go to the G Suite Marketplace SDK under APIs & Services, navigate to the Publish page and fill out the form there. That's where they ask you for your text assets, URLs and graphic assets. Also, if you haven't already published the add-on before, Google will review the add-on before publishing it.

[image]